# Changing Campy index downtube shifters to 'only' do friction shifting

Tags: campagnolo, downtube-shifter

How do you change Campy down tube C-Record indexed shifters to be friction shifters? I don't like index shifters as they limit your options with the cassette you can use.

Mine are Campagnolo Veloce.

Comment: Can you point us to the part that you're using? I don't see a Campy Veloce downtube shifter to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with those shifters but perhaps this will be of assistance: [Campy Syncro 2 shifters](http://www.tearsforgears.com/2005/11/campagnolo-syncro-ii-shifters.html)

> The left/front shifter is a standard friction shifter.
>
> To convert (the right one) to pure friction, you can actually just remove the springs and optionally the boss collar -- the springs are all that is required to (re)move.

Comment: @Criggie Thanks for that, I normally would have done so but quite honestly, I'm more than a little out of my depth with a lot of Campy's stuff and didn't want to confuse anybody by making assumptions.